# salt added to fat acts as a binding agent?

Tags: food-science

I made maseca dumplings. Maseca is the flour obtained by soaking corn in lime. Maseca needs to be mixed with water to make a dough. The dumplings are added to gently boiling water. When I used only water and maseca to make the dumplings they held together. If I used water and fat (oil or lard) then the dumplings fell apart. If I used water, fat and salt they held together. The quantity of salt matters, too little and they fall apart quickly. Furthermore:

- Salt added to the water retarded the decay of a dumpling w/o salt.
- Adding a dumpling w/o salt to salted water lengthened survival time.
  Apparently it is the agitation of the bubbles in boiling water that causes them to fall apart, as they stay together at a simmer up to 195-200 but as the bubbling starts to increase they start to fall apart; at a full boil they fall apart quicker. Those without lard could withstand a rolling boil.
  Can anyone explain this phenomenon?
  I'm asking why salt acts as a binder but I don't if that is actually what is occurring.
  Thanks